# Running .Net Tasks in parallel that return different objects

Tags: vb.net, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await

I am currently looking at processing 2 data downloads from a WCF service that return collections of different objects and was wondering if there was a better method than running the two asynchronous tasks synchronously.

In this case can I implement as [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall.aspx) or [Task.WhenAny](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany.aspx) methodology to run these tasks in parallel?

```
Public Property Users As IEnumerable(Of UserDto)
    Get
        Return _users
    End Get
    Set(value As IEnumerable(Of UserDto))
        _users = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Users")
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ApplicationRoles() As IEnumerable(Of ApplicationRoleDto)
    Get
        Return _roles
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IEnumerable(Of ApplicationRoleDto))
        _roles = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("ApplicationRoles")
    End Set
End Property

Private Async Sub GetUserDetails()
    Users = Await _serviceHelper.GetUsers()
    ApplicationRoles = Await _serviceHelper.GetApplicationRoles
End Sub
```

**Possible solution**

I could use the [Task Parrallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) but I am not sure if this is the most efficient method, plus I can't await the return.

```
Parallel.Invoke(Sub() Users = _serviceHelper.GetUsers(),
                    Sub() ApplicationRoles = _serviceHelper.GetApplicationRoles())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` should work just fine. Pardon if the syntax isn't quite correct; my VB is incredibly rusty:

```
Private Async Function GetUserDetailsAsync() As Task
  Dim UsersTask = _serviceHelper.GetUsersAsync()
  Dim ApplicationRolesTask = _serviceHelper.GetApplicationRolesAsync
  Await Task.WhenAll(UsersTask, ApplicationRolesTask);
  Users = Await UsersTask
  ApplicationRoles = Await ApplicationRolesTask
End Function
```

I also took the liberty of changing your `Sub` to a `Function` (you should avoid `Async Sub`), and making your `Async` methods end with `Async`, [as per the convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).

Comment: Looks good. Is there a reason to await the result as in Users = Await UsersTask rather than calling Users = UsersTask.Result?

Comment: `Result` will wrap any exceptions inside an `AggregateException`, so I prefer `Await` for that reason.